# What does boost::asio::io_service::run() actually do?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have implemented a TCP socket client that connects to the server and uses `boost::asio::read()` and `boost::asio::write()` calls.

A bit like this:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_client.cpp

However, in my implementation I'm not calling `boost::asio::io_service::run()` at all and the socket reads/writes still work. What is the purpose of that service in the context of a socket client? Do I need to **run** the service?

Comment: So you don't have a line like `std::thread t([&io_service](){ io_service.run(); });` (copied from the source you link to) in your code? Can you please create a [mcve] of *your* code to show us?

Comment: My client is using Qt's event loop and it just instantiates the service. My question is what does the run method do? Is that an event loop for asynchronous operations?

Comment: `io_service::run` processes handlers. Handlers are created by functions which work in async mode like `async_read` , `async_write`, these functions return immediately, In your case `asio::read` doesn't create any handler, it is blocking function, so there is no need to run `io_service::run` which calls handlers.

Comment: @rafix07 I think you meant `asio::read`? Please convert that to an answer :)

Comment: @juzzlin yep, it was typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`io_service::run` processes handlers. Handlers are created by functions which work 
in async mode like `async_read`, `async_write`. These functions return immediately.
Handler is queued, function returns, `io_service::run` processes this handler later. 
In your case `asio::read` doesn't create any handler, it is blocking function, so there is no need to call `io_service::run`.